# I don't understand this meaning of so

Tags: adverbs

I was searching about the meaning of so but I didn't understand this meaning

d: most certainly : INDEED

you did so do it

It's from maerriam webster.
can you give me another examples?
is it supposed to be "you did so, do it" or "you did, so do it"?

Answer (score 4):

It's a colloquial, idiomatic usage. The commas you suggest are unnecessary because "so" is acting as just an intensifier; the meaning is unchanged from "You did do it."

The same construction often uses "too."

"I didn't eat your sandwich."
"You did too eat it!"
"Did not!"
"Did too!"

Comment: This usage is typical of a childish argument, and "so" or "too" is stressed in the pronunciation: "You did SO eat it!".